# Quickblox multiple filter on users

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am using Quickblox for my chat app and i want to get last 30 online male or female users.I used "tag" for gender and "last request at" for online state.When i get users with tag,i don't extend request for online users so i changed my design and i keep gender information in "full name".At this point i need to request once and use 2 filter(last request at and full name).I used rest api and Quickblox classes but they didn't work.

Is it possible to use multiple filter for user module?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
 /**
 Retrieve all Users for current account with extended request

 @param extendedRequest Dictionary with extended request
 @param responsePage Pagination parameters
 @param successBlock Block with response, page and users instances if request succeded
 @param errorBlock Block with response instance if request failed

 @return An instance of QBRequest for cancel operation mainly.
 */
+ (QB_NONNULL QBRequest *)usersWithExtendedRequest:(QB_NONNULL NSDictionary QB_GENERIC(NSString *, NSString *) *)extendedRequest
                                              page:(QB_NULLABLE QBGeneralResponsePage *)responsePage
                                      successBlock:(QB_NULLABLE void (^)(QBResponse * QB_NONNULL_S response, QBGeneralResponsePage * QB_NULLABLE_S page, NSArray QB_GENERIC(QBUUser *) * QB_NULLABLE_S users))successBlock
                                        errorBlock:(QB_NULLABLE void (^)(QBResponse * QB_NONNULL_S response))errorBlock;
```

As extended request use this filters: http://quickblox.com/developers/Users#Filters

Comment: i'm already asking that is it possible to use this method with multiple filter?

Comment: It contains NSDictionary for extendedRequest. Just put all your filters there.

Comment: I'm already using it but what if i use second filter? filters[@"filter[]"] =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"date last_request_at gt %@",dateString];

    [User getAllUsersWithFilter:filters completion:^(NSArray *users, QBError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            block(allUsers,nil);
        }
    }];

Comment: Do you know how NSDictionary works? Just make 2 entries there. Please read keys for it in the link upper.

Comment: But what if i want to filter with full name and last request at .these are using same parameter name ,filter[],how can it be possible?

Comment: You are actually completely right. The doc about extended request should be updated. For now use this example of extended request (should be same for users): http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Filters